# Sequential Division verilog

Tags: binary, verilog, division

Can anyone tell me what should be the width of dividend and divisor in sequential division. As of now i have designed the divider which has WIDTH_DIVID=2*wIDTH_DIVIS. If i voilate this relation my division fails. Can anyone help me with this 
My verilog code as show below

```
//  Description:  module for serial Divider
//  The dividend is loaded into the accumulator along with the guard bit.
//  Then the 2's complement of the divisor is added to the upperpart of the
//  accumulator along with the guard bit.Then the MSB of the accumulator is
//  tested.
//  1. If it is cleared then 1 bit left shift of the accumulator is done and 
//     one is concantinated to the LSB of the accumulator.
//  2. If is is not cleared then the accumulator contents are shifted 1 bit 
//     left.
//  After the division upper part of the accumulator contains the remainder 
//  and lower part contains the quotient.
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
module division(//global inputs
        i_clk,i_rst,
        //outputs
        o_quotient,o_remainder,o_done,o_overflow,
        //input
        i_dividend,i_divisor,i_start
        );

   //parameter declarations 
   parameter DIVIS_WIDTH =2;        //width for divisor 
   parameter DIVID_WIDTH =2*DIVIS_WIDTH;       //width for dividend,DIVID_WIDTH=2*DIVIS_WIDTH
   localparam NPOWER = 6;                          //divisor width<=2**NPOWER  
   localparam NULL_VECTOR_S=32'h00000000;
   localparam S0= 2'd0;
   localparam S1= 2'd1;
   localparam S2= 2'd2;

   //global inputs
   input i_clk;
   input i_rst;

   //outputs
   output reg [DIVIS_WIDTH:0] o_quotient;
   output reg [DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0] o_remainder;
   output reg           o_overflow;
   output reg           o_done;


   //input           
   input [DIVID_WIDTH-1:0]  i_dividend;
   input [DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0]  i_divisor;
   input            i_start;      //indicates start of division

   // reg and wire declarations
   reg [DIVID_WIDTH:0]      dividend_i;    //Add extra guard bit
   reg [DIVIS_WIDTH:0]      divisor_i;    //Add extra guard bit
   reg [DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0]    divisor_rect_i;   //divisor used to check overflow
   wire             signquot_i;       //Sign of quotient
   wire             signremain_i;    //Sign of remainder
   reg [DIVID_WIDTH+DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0] accumulator_i;   // Shift register which holds both remainder and quotient
   reg [DIVIS_WIDTH:0]           aluout_i;        //Used to add the upperpart of the shift register and the divisor
   reg [NPOWER-1:0]              count_i;        //No.of iterations
   reg                   pos_i;
   reg                   neg_i;
   reg [2:0]                 state;
   reg [2:0]                 nextstate; 
   reg                   done_i;


   //Sign product of quotient and remainder
   assign   signquot_i=((i_dividend[DIVID_WIDTH-1] ^ i_divisor[DIVIS_WIDTH-1]));
   assign   signremain_i=(i_dividend[DIVID_WIDTH-1]);

  always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)
     begin 
    if(i_rst==1)begin 
       dividend_i<=0;
       divisor_i<=0;
       divisor_rect_i<=0;
    end else begin
       divisor_rect_i<=i_divisor;
           dividend_i<=({1'b0,i_dividend});
       divisor_i<=(~({1'b0,i_divisor})+1);  
    end
     end // else: !if(i_rst==1)


   //Sequential Division 
   always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)                         
     begin
    if (i_rst==1)                     
      accumulator_i <=0;
    else begin  
       if(i_start==1) 
         accumulator_i<={dividend_i[DIVID_WIDTH-1:0],1'b0};   // Load Dividend in shift register
       else if(pos_i==1)                                    
         accumulator_i<=({aluout_i[DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0],accumulator_i[DIVID_WIDTH-DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0],1'b1});//({newaccu_i[DIVID_WIDTH-1:0],1'b1});//shiting the new register value by one bit left and concantinatinf one at the LSB
       else if(neg_i==1)
         accumulator_i<=({accumulator_i[DIVID_WIDTH-1:0],1'b0});//Use the previous register value and shift 1 bit left
    end
     end // always@ (posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst or posedge i_start)

   //Adding the divisor to the upper part of the Shift register             
   always@(accumulator_i,divisor_i)
     begin 
    aluout_i<=accumulator_i[DIVID_WIDTH : DIVID_WIDTH-DIVIS_WIDTH]+ divisor_i; 
    //  newaccu_i<= ({aluout_i, accumulator_i[DIVID_WIDTH-DIVIS_WIDTH-1:0]}); 
     end

   //Control of states for division   
   always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)      
     begin
    if (i_rst == 1) begin      
       state   <= S0; 
       count_i <=0;             
    end  else begin     
       state <= nextstate;   
       if (state==S1)
         count_i <= count_i - 1;
       else if (state==S0)
         count_i <= (DIVIS_WIDTH); 
    end
     end // always@ (posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst)


   //generating the control signals pos_i and neg_i to control division 
   always@(state,i_start,aluout_i,count_i)
     begin  
    case (state)
      S0 :begin 
         pos_i <= 0;
         neg_i <= 0;
         if (i_start==1)
           nextstate <= S1; 
         else 
           nextstate <= S0;
      end 
      S1 : begin 
         neg_i <= aluout_i[DIVIS_WIDTH];      
         pos_i <= ~(aluout_i[DIVIS_WIDTH]); 
         if (count_i==NULL_VECTOR_S[NPOWER_WIDTH-1])
           nextstate <= S2; // Done 
         else 
           nextstate <= S1;// Next sub&shift
      end
      S2 : begin 
         pos_i <= 0;
         neg_i <= 0;                                           
         nextstate <= S0; 
      end 
      default: begin
         pos_i <= 0;
         neg_i <= 0;                                           
         nextstate <= S0;              
      end
    endcase // case (state)
     end // always@ (state,i_start,aluout_i,count_i)

   //done signal to indicate end of division   
   always@(posedge i_clk or posedge i_rst) 
     begin  
    if(i_rst==1) begin
       done_i<= 0;
    end else  begin 
       done_i <= (count_i==1)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
    end
     end

   //Assigning the outputs for unsigned division   

   always@(accumulator_i,done_i)
     begin
    o_done<=done_i;
    o_remainder<=accumulator_i[DIVID_WIDTH:DIVID_WIDTH-DIVIS_WIDTH+1];
    o_quotient<=(accumulator_i[DIVIS_WIDTH:0]); 
    o_overflow<=(((accumulator_i[DIVID_WIDTH:DIVID_WIDTH-DIVIS_WIDTH+1])>=divisor_rect_i))? 1'b1 : 1'b0;     
     end 
endmodule // division
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear on the terms used:

> a ÷ b = c, a is called the dividend or numerator, b the divisor or
>   denominator and the result c is called the quotient

Source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29).

The input width of the dividend (numerator) and divisor (denominator) will determine the size of the quotient. Adding lsbs (fractional bits) to the inputs will increase the quotient precision.

The final required widths should be the same as using the `/` operator. Try running this along side your code to help spot errors. For required width calculation I strongly suggest working through some examples on paper. Start by dividing 4 bit numbers and move up to larger numbers 5,6 bits to understand the pattern of bit growth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a parameterized serial divider in system verilog.

```
// returns max value ('1) if divide by zero or overflow occurs.

module unsigned_serial_divide #(
   parameter N_WIDTH = 16       // Size of dividend
  ,parameter D_WIDTH = 16       // Size of divisor
  ,parameter Q_WIDTH = 16       // Size of quotient
  ,parameter F_WIDTH = 0        // Number of fractional bits in quotient.
  )(
   input wire clk
  ,input wire reset
  ,input wire go      // hold high for continuous calculation or stobe high for single calculation
  ,input wire [N_WIDTH-1:0] dividend
  ,input wire [D_WIDTH-1:0] divisor
  ,output reg [Q_WIDTH-1:0] quotient    // maintains last complete calculation.
  //,output wire overflow               // NOT IMPLEMENTED
  ,output wire done                         // stobes high if go is held high or indicated when single calculation complete
  );

  localparam COUNT_WIDTH = $clog2(Q_WIDTH);
  localparam [COUNT_WIDTH-1:0] DIVIDE_COUNTS = (COUNT_WIDTH)'(Q_WIDTH - 1'b1);

  localparam WN_WIDTH = N_WIDTH + F_WIDTH;
  localparam WD_WIDTH = D_WIDTH + DIVIDE_COUNTS;

  localparam CALC_WIDTH = ((WN_WIDTH > WD_WIDTH) ? WN_WIDTH : WD_WIDTH) + 1;

  reg  busy;
  reg  [COUNT_WIDTH-1:0]  divide_count;
  reg  [WN_WIDTH-1:0]       working_dividend;
  reg  [WD_WIDTH-1:0]       working_divisor;
  reg  [Q_WIDTH-1:0]      working_quotient;

  initial begin
    busy <= 0;    
    divide_count <= 0;  
    working_dividend <= 0;
    working_divisor <= 0;
    working_quotient <= 0;
    quotient <= 0;
  end

  // Subtract with sign bit
  wire [CALC_WIDTH-1:0] subtract_calc = {1'b0, working_dividend} - {1'b0, working_divisor};  

  // subtract_positive = (working_dividend > working_divisor);
  wire subtract_positive = ~subtract_calc[CALC_WIDTH-1];

  // if the next bit in quotient should be set then subtract working_divisor from working_dividend
  wire [WN_WIDTH-1:0] dividend_next = (subtract_positive) ? subtract_calc[WN_WIDTH-1:0] : working_dividend;

  wire [WD_WIDTH-1:0] divisor_next = working_divisor >> 1;   

  wire [Q_WIDTH-1:0] quotient_next = (working_quotient << 1) | (subtract_positive); 

  always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) begin
      busy <= 0;
      divide_count <= 0;
      working_dividend <= 0;
      working_divisor <= 0;
      working_quotient <= 0;
      quotient <= 0;
    end else begin
      if (go & ~busy) begin
        busy <= 1;
        divide_count <= DIVIDE_COUNTS;              
        working_dividend <= dividend << F_WIDTH;                // scale the numerator up by the fractional bits
        working_divisor  <= divisor  << DIVIDE_COUNTS;  // align divisor to the quotient        
        working_quotient <= 0;
      end else begin            
        if (divide_count == 0) begin
          if (busy == 1) begin
            quotient <= quotient_next;
          end
          busy <= 0;
        end else begin
          divide_count <= divide_count - 1'b1;      
        end         
        working_dividend <= dividend_next;
        working_divisor <= divisor_next; 
        working_quotient <= quotient_next;                  
      end
    end
  end   

  assign done = ~busy;  

endmodule
```